# How do I make this script execute only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this great script. It takes my whole webpage, and shows a back side of it on a `<button>` click. Love it. But I only want it to flip one time, and then lock on that flip. How can I disable the clicking of the div once it flips?

```
(function() {


$(document).ready(function() {
    var count, rotateX;
    rotateX = 0;
    count = 0;
    $(".container").on("mousedown", function() {
      rotateX += 180;
      $("body").css({
        "transform": "scale(1.2)"
      });
      if (count % 2 === 0) {
        return $(".container").css({
          "box-shadow": "0px 32px 56px rgba(0,0,0,.1)"
        });
      } else {
        return $(".container").css({
          "box-shadow": "0px -32px 56px rgba(0,0,0,.1)"
        });
      }
    });
    return $(".container").on("mouseup", function() {
      $(this).css({
        "transform": "rotateX(" + rotateX + "deg)"
      });
      $("body").css({
        "transform": "scale(1)"
      });
      if (count % 2 === 0) {
        $("body").css({
          "background": "transparent"
        });
        $(".container").css({
          "box-shadow": "none"
        });
      } else {
        $("body").css({
          "background": "#165730"
        });
        $(".container").css({
          "box-shadow": "0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1)"
        });
      }
      return count++;
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jquery`'s [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to acheive what you're trying now

Probably you need to change your event handler as,

```
return $(".container").one("mouseup", function() {....
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: David, it's perfect. I literally had to add one letter to the `.on(`

Comment: Hahah awesome!! Why isn't all of life this easy??

Comment: Can you please mark my response as answered then? ;-)

Comment: Yes!! Absolutely. It won't allow me to for another 7 min tho. I think it's because I have a low rep.

Comment: Got it.. No issues @JonathanSafa